# image not showing in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm inserting an **img** control in every cell of the last column of my grid. But the image is not showing (an **X** appears).

I tried putting an html image somewhere else in the page, to make sure the path to the image is correct, and in that html image, the picture appears. When checking the `view source` of the page, both the html image and the image within the gridview have the same `ImageUrl`.

Any idea of what is missing here?

The image should be inserted here:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="RequestStatusId" HeaderText="Status" 
                            ReadOnly="true" />
```

**aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwRequests" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="odsRequests" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" 
                    CssClass="GridStyle" onrowdatabound="gvwRequests_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Request" DataTextField="Request"
                            SortExpression="Request" CommandName="OpenRequest" />                            
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="RequestDate" 
                            SortExpression="RequestDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestNbr" HeaderText="RequestNbr" 
                            SortExpression="RequestNbr" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="PartNumber" 
                            SortExpression="PartNumber" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="Brand" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" 
                            SortExpression="Customer" />                            
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestStatusId" HeaderText="Status" 
                            ReadOnly="true" />
                    </Columns>
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPagerStyle" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void gvwRequests_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            string sColor = ListOfColorStatus.Find(item => item.RequestStatusId == Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text)).Color;
            string sStatus = ListOfColorStatus.Find(item => item.RequestStatusId == Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text)).Status;
            img.ImageUrl = "../images/" + sColor + "_ball.png";
            img.AlternateText = sColor;
            img.ToolTip = sStatus;
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(img);
        }
    }
```

**Source:**

```
<img src="../images/Yellow_ball.png" alt="Yellow" /> --> Appears
                <div>
    <table class="GridStyle" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvwRequests" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Request</th><th scope="col">RequestDate</th><th scope="col">PONbr</th><th scope="col">PartNumber</th><th scope="col">Qty</th><th scope="col">Model</th><th scope="col">Brand</th><th scope="col">Customer</th><th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr><tr class="GridRowStyle">
            <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvwRequests','OpenRequest$0')">2</a></td><td>03-12-2015</td><td>22222</td><td>32151458121</td><td>5</td><td>BLACKBERRY 8520</td><td>RESEARCH IN MOTION</td><td>CABLE &amp; WIRELESS ANTIGUA LTD</td><td><img title="Pending" src="../images/Yelow_ball.png" alt="Yelow" style="border-width:0px;" /></td> --> Does not appear
```

Comment: Can you insert the directory structure of the site, so we can see the relative path of this page, to the Image directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, images is one level up from your current directory, and that's where the file should be.

Have you debugged, copied that path, pasted it into another tab or window, and verified you're not getting a 404 error? It sounds like your path is off is none of the images are showing up.

Maybe you need to map it from site root using the `"~/"` or `"/"` syntax instead?

**EDIT**

Yup, your path is wrong. Try "/images" or "~/images" and it'll probably work. (Assuming that's at site root)

You're in a dynamic control - pathing on an ASP.NET control doesn't work quite the same as HTML...